# Create a new table based on a query SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query

```
with x as 
(select row_number() over(partition by FirstName order by Investment_DT desc) as rn, *
from [dbSuppHousing].[dbo].[tblABC])
select Login_Name
      ,r.Role_Name
      ,Investment_DT
      ,FirstName     
      ,LastName
      ,Login_Name
      ,Investment_DT
      ,Investment_ID
from x join tblUsers t 
on t.UserName = x.Login_Name

join tblUser_Roles ur on t.User_Id=ur.USER_ID
join tblRoles r on r.Role_Id=ur.Role_ID
where x.rn = 1

order by x.FirstName
```

I want to insert the result of this query into another table as is.

Typically I use a query like:

```
insert  into tblABC2
select * from tblABC
```

But I'm not sure how to do this in this case which is a query which begins with `with x as`

Comment: `WITH my_cte AS (...) SELECT * INTO tblABC2 FROM tblABC ...  `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with x as 
(select row_number() over(partition by FirstName order by Investment_DT desc) as rn, *
from [dbSuppHousing].[dbo].[tblABC])
select Login_Name
      ,r.Role_Name
      ,Investment_DT
      ,FirstName     
      ,LastName
      ,Login_Name
      ,Investment_DT
      ,Investment_ID
into #temptable
from x join tblUsers t 
on t.UserName = x.Login_Name
join tblUser_Roles ur on t.User_Id=ur.USER_ID
join tblRoles r on r.Role_Id=ur.Role_ID
where x.rn = 1
-- order by x.FirstName
```

You can use `into` to insert into the table you need. Also note that you can't do an `order by` when doing this (which has been commented out).

Comment: does this temptable containh rgw columns from the joined tables too? like r.Role_Name?

Comment: no..if you need it to be in the table, you should `select` them.

Answer (score 0):

`with x as (...) insert into tbl select * from x`

So, `insert` should be directly after all CTEs used in the query.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to put the insert statement between the common table expression (CTE) and your select statement:

```
with x as 
(select row_number() over(partition by FirstName order by Investment_DT desc) as rn, *
from [dbSuppHousing].[dbo].[tblABC])

/*
    place insert statement here
*/

select Login_Name
      ,r.Role_Name
      ,Investment_DT
      ,FirstName     
      ,LastName
      ,Login_Name
      ,Investment_DT
      ,Investment_ID
from x join tblUsers t 
on t.UserName = x.Login_Name

join tblUser_Roles ur on t.User_Id=ur.USER_ID
join tblRoles r on r.Role_Id=ur.Role_ID
where x.rn = 1

order by x.FirstName
```

If you are running this on SQL Server 2008+, you need to ensure that any  statement previous to the CTE is terminated with a semicolon.